# Get values from from dynamic registered user controls

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

In my main .aspx page I have a placeholder in which it get registered dynamically two types of user controls.

```
case "1":
   var control = (ControlType)LoadControl("~/PathToControl.ascx");
   control.Property = value;
   control.Initialize();
   placeholder.controls.add(control);
break;
case "2":
   var control1 = (ControlType)LoadControl("~/PathToControl1.ascx");
   control1.Property = value;
   control1.Initialize();
   placeholder.controls.add(control1);
break;
```

Each control has some user controls.

Now, in the main page I have a submit button and I want to get the values of each user coltrol from the above custom control.
I tried to get the controls of the placeholder but the placeholder after the postback is empty.

```
if(placeholder.Controls.count>0){
  var userControl = ((UserControlType)placeholder.Controls[0]);
  var controlName = userControl.FindControl("ControlName") as TextBox;
}
```

I tried also to build the custom controls on page_init but I still can't get the user controls.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

**SOLUTION**

The dynamic user controls must be set in Init Event on each and every visit.

For more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic4

Comment: why do you cast it to ControlType ?

Comment: Because the control except the user controls, has also some properties. Those properties returns the value of each control. Something like get{return textBoxControl.Text}

Comment: is that work for you ???

Comment: no, not yet. The first attempt was not success. I am still working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls must be registered in Init event

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
   case "1":
        var control = (ControlType)LoadControl("~/PathToControl.ascx");
        control.ID = "controlID";
        placeholder.controls.add(control);
  break;
  case "2":
      var control1 = (ControlType)LoadControl("~/PathToControl1.ascx");
      control.ID = "controlID_1";
      placeholder.controls.add(control1);
   break;
base.OnInit(e);
}
```

set whatever properties you want after the Init

```
case "1":
  var control = (ControlType)placeholder.findControl("ControlID");
  control.Property = value;
 control.Initialize();
break;
case "2":
 var control1 = (ControlType)placeholder.findControl("ControlID_1");
 control1.Property = value;
 control1.Initialize();
break;
```

After page's post back

```
void LoadControls(){
   case "1":
    var control = (ControlType)placeholder.findControl("ControlID");
    var txtControl =  control.FindControl("controlName") as TextBox;
   break;
   case "2":
    var control1 = (ControlType)placeholder.findControl("ControlID_1");
    var txtControl_1 =  control1.FindControl("controlName") as TextBox;
   break;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the user will click the submit button, the values will be posted with the form. Here is the easiest way to get the values:

1. When you create the dynamic control, set the ID property, for example:

   `control1.ID = "control1";`
2. On the postback, retrieve the value from the form:

   `var control1Value = Request.Form["control1"];`

Comment: this is not a solution. I can't get a user custom control by this way.

Comment: The custom control ultimately produces an HTML element (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx). In order for this solution to work, you may need an additional statement in step 1: control1.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, this solution retrieves the value of the HTML element that the custom control produces. You may not need to reconstitute the custom control on postback if you only need its value.

Comment: trebormf thanks for you answer and your comments. I found the solution so the next time I will try the one you suggested me.